# Sub-domains keeps redirecting me to Main web-site

Tags: linux, dns, apache-http-server, centos, mysql

I have just upgraded my version of LAMP Environment. Rest all the things are working fine but with Sub-domains i have a challenge.

I have a Main website abc.biz and 5 to 6 sub-domains with it as aaa.abc.biz, site.abc.com. Every time i hit any sub-domain it redirects me to the main site. Please help.

My complete configuration is as below:

- Centos-6.6
- php 5.4.29
- mysql 5.1.57
- apache 2.4.12

I also went to one of the post regarding the same issue but that also dint helped. My current httpd-vhosts.conf is as below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin nikhil@abc.biz
    DocumentRoot "/mnt/docroot/abc"
    ServerName abc.biz
    ServerAlias *.abc.biz
    ErrorLog "logs/abc.biz-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/abc.biz-access_log" common
<Directory />
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/mnt/docroot/aaa"
    ServerName aaa.abc.biz
<Directory />
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the culprit is the fact that you in your first `<VirtualHost>` you have a `ServerAlias *.abc.biz`. Looks like that one covers any subdomains as well.

Here's a snippet from my apache config, and it works for me. This is what I do for subdomains, and I have a lot of them:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName              example.com
        ServerAlias             www.example.com
        DocumentRoot            /usr/www/example.com/http/
        ScriptAlias  /cgi-bin/  /usr/www/example.com/http/cgi-bin/

        ErrorLog                /var/log/www/example.com/error.log
        CustomLog               /var/log/www/example.com/access.log combined
        <Directory />
                Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName              somesubdomain.example.com
        ServerAlias             www.somesubdomain.example.com
        DocumentRoot            /usr/www/somesubdomain.example.com/http/

        # Shared log file with main domain
        ErrorLog                /var/log/www/example.com/error.log
        CustomLog               /var/log/www/example.com/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```